# Google Content Service Await Error when Executing

Tags: c#, asynchronous, gdata

I am trying to push through our product list to Google with the following code:

```
string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/keya.p12");
            String serviceAccountEmail = "#######@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
            var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@path, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
            var init = new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
            {
                Scopes = new[] { Google.Apis.Content.v2.ContentService.Scope.Content }
            }.FromCertificate(certificate);

            ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(init);

            // Create the service.
            service = new Google.Apis.Content.v2.ContentService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "MY APP",
            });
service.Products.Insert(p, ######).Execute();
```

but, I am getting this error on that line no matter what I do:

> Method
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage].AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted:
>   type argument 'Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage]'
>   violates the constraint of type parameter 'TAwaiter'.

I am running this code from within a WebAPI controller. I have also tried a Generic Handler and get the same error.  One reference I found said to update my Microsoft.Bcl package, which I have done with no change.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you update the whole Google.Apis.Calendar.v3 library.
In your NuGet console, execute `Install-Package Google.Apis.Calendar.v3` to get the latest version of the package and it's dependents.

I was getting the same error when making calendar calls to a service account. I was using version 1.8.1.820 of the library. Updating solved the problem for me.